# JwPlayer - Using javascript generated URL as file location

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have a javascript that generate the URL of the file I want to stream. i.e

```
var myURL;
//javascript codes here
document.write(myURL); //will output something like this - http://domain.com/file.mp4
```

And I want to use that as my file. I tried doing this but it does not work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player1').setup({
file: 'document.write(newURL);',    
width: '640',
height: '360'
});
</script>
```

Is this possible? If so what should be the correct approach on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player1').setup({
file: newURL,  
width: '640',
height: '360'
});
</script>
```